# Android uianimator: How can I get an EditText value, when a hint is set

Tags: android, unit-testing, android-edittext, hint

I have an `EditText` field with a hint specified. For example:

```
<EditText
  android:id="@+id/myedittext"
  android:layout_width="wrap_content"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  android:hint="My special hint" />
```

In my Android uianimator testcase, I have the following code:

```
UiObject editText = new UiObject(new UiSelector().resourceId("my.package:id/myedittext"));
System.out.println(editText.getText());
```

The `editText.getText()` statement returns the hint when the `EditText` is empty. Now I have a case in which I want to be sure that the `EditText` is empty. The hint in my case is a value which could be a legit value.

Is there a way to get around this?

Comment: I decided to not use the uiautomator as I got more problems with cross android version testing.